# How to add Straigh line as legend of a graph in Flex

Tags: apache-flex

I want to show the elements of legend of a graph as straight line in Flex instead of the default colored box which comes ,basically the legend should be straight lines of different colors i have tried adding straight lines but as legend items but it was not working any help will highly appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

Below style may help you it gives same look and fill as you want like line......: -

```
<mx:Style>
        @namespace mx "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx";
        mx|Legend {
            labelPlacement:left;
            markerHeight:2;
            markerWidth:30;
        }
    </mx:Style>
```